# Oracle - measure time of reading blob files using sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, blob

ive got a problem for which i couldnt find answwer so far.
Is there a way to read blob file from oracle table using sql or pl/sql and measure time of reading it? I mean like reading whole of it, i dont need it displayed anywhere. All i found was to read 4000 bytes of file but thats not enough.
For importing there is simply
SET TIMING ON and OFF option in sqlplus but using select on tablle gives only small portion of file and doesnt matter how big it is, it always takes the same time pretty much.
Any help anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can get some timings in a PL/SQL block using `dbms_utility.get_time` as LalitKumarB suggested. The initial select is (almost) instant though, it's reading through or processing the data that's really measurable. This is reading a blob with three different 'chunk' sizes to show the difference it makes:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_start number;
  l_blob blob;
  l_byte raw(1);
  l_16byte raw(16);
  l_kbyte raw(1024);
begin
  l_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
  select b into l_blob from t42 where rownum = 1; -- your own query here obviously
  dbms_output.put_line('select: '
    || (dbms_utility.get_time - l_start) || ' hsecs');

  l_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
  for i in 1..dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob) loop
    l_byte := dbms_lob.substr(l_blob, 1, i);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('single byte: '
    || (dbms_utility.get_time - l_start) || ' hsecs');

  l_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
  for i in 1..(dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob)/16) loop
    l_16byte := dbms_lob.substr(l_blob, 16, i);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('16 bytes: '
    || (dbms_utility.get_time - l_start) || ' hsecs');

  l_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
  for i in 1..(dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob)/1024) loop
    l_kbyte := dbms_lob.substr(l_blob, 1024, i);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('1024 bytes: '
    || (dbms_utility.get_time - l_start) || ' hsecs');
end;
/
```

For a sample blob that gives something like:

```
anonymous block completed
select: 0 hsecs
single byte: 950 hsecs
16 bytes: 61 hsecs
1024 bytes: 1 hsecs
```

So clearly reading the blob in larger chunks is more efficient. So your "measure time of reading it" is a bit flexible...

Comment: Hey, thats pretty nice stuff you wrote here however (i cant test it right now) would that be able to read file which has like 50 MB? or even greater ones? As if i remember correctly there are some limits on it. Also it seems that you are using dbms_lob.substr - will it read any kind of file? From what ive seen so far lob.read or something like that was used

Comment: @user3494351 - it should be able to read any size; the only limit is the buffer size. (I think the numbers above were for about 10KB, but I just ran it with 50MB with the largest chunk size - 4931 hsec with 1KB chunks). `substr` will read a `BLOB`, yes, and returns `RAW`. You could `read` instead; one is a function, the other a procedure, I don't think it makes much difference. All I'm doing is making it actually traverse the whole thing; just selecting it is very quick and I guess you want some idea how long it would take to process the data it contains.

Comment: Hey, yes i need to check how long does oracle needs to read the file.. well which actually might be passed later on to application etc but i did not wanted any application overhead or anything. Just pure database time. Thanks a lot for it!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have the solution to access the BLOB data. For getting the time, use `DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME` before and after the step in your `PL/SQL` code. You could declare two variables, `start_time` and `end_time` to capture the respective times, and just subtract them to get the time elapsed/taken for the step.

See this as an example, http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/plsql-new-features-and-enhancements-11gr1.php

Comment: Actually i dont have solution to access BLOB data. Just part of it (4000 bytes) - while some blob files inserted to table are waaay bigger ;/

Comment: Ok, so you want to know how to read the BLOB too? So, I just answered the second part of your question.

Comment: Yes you answered part of question - still good, and usefull tho ;] but yea i also need a way to read whole blob without writing special applications for it.. as i said i just need oracle to read it to measure timme.. i dont need to see it or anything